# MySQL data against each month

Tags: mysql

I have a table for users like this

```
id   |   username  | name   | join_date
-----+-------------+--------+-------------
1    |  asdasd     | name1  | timestamp
2    |  asdas1     | name2  | timestamp
3    |  asdas2     | name3  | timestamp
4    |  asdas3     | name4  | timestamp
```

Each user needs to pay for a monthly subscription. Needs to take the report if user paid or not.

So I created another table for adding month data ( admin will add each month manually )

```
id  |  month_number  | year
----+----------------+---------
1   | 02             | 2017   // Case Feb 2014
3   | 03             | 2017   // Case Mar 2014
```

how to connect these two tables ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to just join them inside queries.
The easiest way for that would be to just put it inside the where clause.... `SELECT payment.month_number, payment.year, users.username FROM users, payment WHERE (users.id = payment.id) AND (users.username = asdasd)`

Answer (score 0):

You will need a table to track the `subscriptions` (second table is not needed actually). `subscriptions` can have user id as Foreign Key, subscription_date and amount columns, e.g.:

```
id  |  user_id  | subscription_date | amount
----+-----------+-------------------+--------
1   |     2     | 2017-03-01        | 100
1   |     1     | 2017-02-01        | 100
```

Comment: how to take defaulter's list in each month ?

Comment: By using `NOT EXISTS` ? e.g. `SELECT u.* FROM users u WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM subscriptions WHERE user_id = u.id AND subscription_date = '2017-02-01');`

Answer (score 0):

if possible Please add the column user_id to the month_date table

and, try this

```
SELECT * 
  FROM users u
  LEFT JOIN month_date m
    ON u.id = m.user_id
```